# Mule Redis connector configuration is not consistent with its document

Tags: redis, mule

Recently we decided to add a cache layer to our mule APIs and Redis came to the scope.

We are at Mule3.8.0 and Redis connector 4.0.0. and we met following issues while configuring:

- How to separate our keys by Redis DB ? This is not mentioned in document and there is only a 'Default Partition Name' in the configuration seems close but whatever value we put there, seems no effect - it will always be db0 containing all the keys, hence we can't really have "dev", "qa" and "test" key sets in the same redis cluster
- The Redis connector document has example as below

  ```
  <redis:sorted-set-select-range-by-index config-   ref="Redis_configuration" key="my_key" start="0" end="-1" />
  ```

however when we tried the samething it complains the 'end' value should be >= 0 hence not usable

- How to configure a connection pool  properly with Redis connector configuration? Not mentioned in document again. The only attribute is the 'Pool Config Reference' and I tried to put a spring bean ref to my own JedisPoolConfig there, seems no effect, and number of the connections remains the same no matter what value I put in that bean.

Thanks in advance If someone could help with these issues above

James

Answer (score 0):

> How to separate our keys by Redis DB ?

You can use Redis in cluster mode with sharing data (http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial)

I don't think you need special configuration in Mule.

I think you mix Partition term in Mule and Partition term in Redis.

Regards,